# Как вычислить сумму значений нескольких range slider?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

```js
$('.filter__slider-element').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      container = $this.closest('.filter__slider'),
      min = parseInt($this.data('min')),
      max = parseInt($this.data('max')),
      from = container.find('.filter__slider-input-from'),
      to = container.find('.filter__slider-input-to'),
      difference = container.find('.filter__slider-differ');



  from.change(function(){      
    $('.filter__slider-element').slider('values', 0, from.val());
  });

  to.change(function(){
    $('.filter__slider-element').slider('values', 1, to.val());
  });

  $this.slider({
    range: true,
    min : min,
    max: max,
    values: [min, max],
    change: function(event, ui) {
      difference.text(ui.values[1] - ui.values[0]);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui){
      from.val(ui.values[0]);
      to.val(ui.values[1]);
      difference.text(ui.values[1] - ui.values[0]);
    },
    create: function(event, ui){
      var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
      from.val(values[0]);
      to.val(values[1]);
      difference.text(values[1] - values[0]);
    }
  });  
});

function calcOne() {
    
  var result = $("#result"); 

  var price = 0; // Начальная стоимость
      

//   price += dif;

  result.text(price);
}
```

```css
.form-row {
  padding: 0 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.filter__slider-display div {
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
}

.calc-res {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="calc calc_1">
              <h3 class="calc__title">Калькулятор </h3>
              <form action="#" class="form form_1">
                
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="filter__slider">
                        <div class="filter__slider-display">
                          <div class="filter__slider-left">
                            <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
                            <input type="text" name="slider" class="filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from" >
                          </div>
                          <div class="filter__slider-right">
                            <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
                            <input type="text" name="slider" class="filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            Difference
                            <span class="filter__slider-differ"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="300"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="filter__slider">
                    <div class="filter__slider-display">
                      <div class="filter__slider-left">
                        <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
                        <input type="text" name="slider" class="filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from" >
                      </div>
                      <div class="filter__slider-right">
                        <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
                        <input type="text" name="slider" class="filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        Difference
                        <span class="filter__slider-differ"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="100"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="calc-res">Итого: <span id="result" >0</span> руб.</div>
                </div>
                
                <input type="submit" value="отправить">
              </form>
              
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как можно вынести значение **difference** для каждого range слайдера jquery ui в функцию calcOne() для расчета стоимости услуг?

[пример на jsbin](https://jsbin.com/lezemuk/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

заменил difference.text(values[1] - values[0]);  на функцию foo и массив arr, calcOne() стала ненужна, подробности смотрите в коде

```js
var arr = [],
  result = $("#result");
$('.filter__slider-element').each(function(i) {
  var $this = $(this),
    container = $this.closest('.filter__slider'),
    min = parseInt($this.data('min')),
    max = parseInt($this.data('max')),
    from = container.find('.filter__slider-input-from'),
    to = container.find('.filter__slider-input-to'),
    difference = container.find('.filter__slider-differ');



  from.change(function() {
    $('.filter__slider-element').slider('values', 0, from.val());
  });

  to.change(function() {
    $('.filter__slider-element').slider('values', 1, to.val());
  });

  arr[i] = 0;
  var foo = function(values) {
    from.val(values[0]);
    to.val(values[1]);
    arr[i] = values[1] - values[0]
    difference.text(arr[i]);
    result.text(arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + (b || 0)
    }, 0));
  }

  $this.slider({
    range: true,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    values: [min, max],
    change: function(event, ui) {
      foo(ui.values)
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      foo(ui.values)
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
      var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
      foo(values)

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-row {
  padding: 0 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.filter__slider-display div {
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
}
.calc-res {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calc calc_1">
    <h3 class="calc__title">Калькулятор </h3>
    <form action="#" class="form form_1">

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="filter__slider">
          <div class="filter__slider-display">
            <div class="filter__slider-left">
              <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
              <input type="text" name="slider" class="filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from">
            </div>
            <div class="filter__slider-right">
              <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
              <input type="text" name="slider" class="filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
            </div>
            <div>
              Difference
              <span class="filter__slider-differ"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="300"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="filter__slider">
          <div class="filter__slider-display">
            <div class="filter__slider-left">
              <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
              <input type="text" name="slider" class="filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from">
            </div>
            <div class="filter__slider-right">
              <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
              <input type="text" name="slider" class="filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
            </div>
            <div>
              Difference
              <span class="filter__slider-differ"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="calc-res">Итого: <span id="result">0</span> руб.</div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="отправить">
    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```